# Clear form inputs after Posting to MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, forms, reset

I created a form that posts data to a MongoDB database. The problem is that when I post I want the input fields to refresh without having to refresh the whole page.

When I call the function resetBooks() I think it clears the form first and then posts nothing, is that right?

How do i get the form to post the data, and then clear the input fields.

```
<div class="booksInput">
  <h4>Add a book</h4>

  <form id="bookForm" method="post" action="/books" 
      target="hiddenFrame" onsubmit="resetBooks()">
       <input class="form-control" name="title" type="text" placeholder="book title">
       <input class="form-control" name="author" type="text" placeholder="author">
       <input class="form-control" name="description" type="text" placeholder="short description">
       <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Book">Submit</button>
  </form>

</div>

<script>
  function resetBooks(){
    document.getElementById('bookForm').reset();
    };

  app.post("/", (req, res)=>{
  let myBook = new Book (req.body);
  myBook.save()
  .then(item =>{
    res.send("Book saved to database");
  })
  .catch(err=>{
    res.status(err).send("unable to save to database");
   });
  });

</script>
```

Comment: I should mention that the resetBooks() function and the app.post() are in separate js files. I'm not sure if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add an arbitrary time offset that should work with most modern browsers.  It used to be only Chrome had issues with this but I know FireFox does now as well.  With the new Edge being Chromium based I think you'll run into similar issues without offsetting things.

I've attached a few screenshots from Firefox's requests because fiddles are horrible for form submissions.

```
function resetBooks(){
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('bookForm').reset();}, 100);    
};
```

[image: Form]

[image: Form Request]

Comment: It works! Thanks so much this one was realy doing my head in.

Comment: It's one of those odd-ball workarounds.  Form submissions typically force a redirect of the browser so the form itself is "gone" but since it was redirected in a different window that wasn't the case in your scenario.  You may want to look into  JQuery/Ajax form submissions if you're trying similar things in the future.  But I'm all for reducing library dependencies.